# Increase space on a ext4 file system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I have the following stats in my Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS file system:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        97G  4.7G   93G   5% /
/dev/sdb         89G   89G     0 100% /mnt/games
```

I need more space in the `/mnt/games` section.

How can I take 75G from 'dev/sda1' and use it in '/dev/sdb'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, you don't (with how you have it currently configured).

Longer answer:

If you have the ability to back up everything and start again then you can use LVM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)) to divide up the 2 physical discs (/dev/sda and /dev/sdb) into what are known as extents, you can then build volumes from these extents. You can then decide how much space each volume needs and assign the right number of extents.

LVM also allows you to dynamically change the number of extents bound to each volume so you can "move" space around (it's a little more complicated as you have to resize the filesystems that are running on top of each volume)

Comment: Thanks! Would it be possible to put a `/mnt/games2` in `/dev/sda1`?